# insert random id in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table called students with a column called student_id. This column is currently empty Is there a function that will automatically generate a random ID and insert into the table for each record.

Thanks

Comment: Why random? You can set the table to auto-increment the id each time you insert a row of data, though. Random gives a risk of duplicate id, something we don't want!

Comment: You got a perfectly valid answer (with links to the manual pages for `RAND()` and `UPDATE`) in the similar question you posted half an hour ago. But you removed the question as soon as it got answered. That doesn't really show you appreciate our efforts.

Comment: Do you know how to cast votes?

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario I'm guessing that `student_id` should be unique and `RAND()` is very likely to give duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [UUID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function.

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALES (UUID(), ...);
```

Or (in your case):

```
UPDATE students SET student_id = UUID();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using  [`UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) to create a unique value like

```
 .... Values(UUID(), "TestUUID");
```